# Azure PR Build gets invalidated when the version file is committed in the build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create an Azure DevOps build pipeline. I have a script in the build pipeline that bumps up the version number, updates the version.h file and commits that file to the git repo. But as soon as this file is committed, the PR shows "Build Not Run":

[image]

I am using [skip ci] tag in the beginning of the commit message but doesn't resolve the problem either. I also tried adding "!/version.h; /*" as filters in the branch build policy. It still didn't make any difference. I have been trying to find solutions on google for a few days but it doesn't look like there are a lot of help posts related to this.

How can I make the Pull Request ignore the latest commit pushed from the build pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess from the image I think this build is being triggered due to the branch policy of having build validation since it sates required check not yet run. Can you check the Build validation policy for this branch and check the build expiration. At a guess this is set to immediately, so when your build pipeline runs and updates the code it immediately invalidates the build validation. If this is the case adding the Path filter on the build validation to exclude the files you are updating should fix the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response. I took a chance and changed the build validation setting to expire 1 hour after main is updated. It did not make any difference because these validation settings are pertaining to the main branch. I am updating the source branch.

Comment: You are creating a loop by updating the source branch. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) it states "A build validation policy queues a new build when a new PR is created or changes are pushed to an existing PR that targets the branch". As such, your build pipeline is altering the PR by committing new code to it which in returns causes the build validation checks again. If you add the path filters to exclude the file you are updating in the build validation it should fix it

Comment: I am using the path filter for the file, still getting the same problem. PR doesn't ignore that file for some reason. Here is the text I added for the filter - **!/Source/Main/version.h; /*** (The intention is to not exclude version.h and include all other files. Please let me know if I am making any syntax error here).

Comment: @user2719051 without seeing your repo structure I couldn't tell if the filter is correct, however at a glance it looks wrong since your referencing source and main. If the file is the only .h file you could use !*.h. If its in the root you would use !version.h . If its in a folder path somewhere in the repo you would use !/path/to/folder/version.h